# Dynamic tree control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am using control named 'tree' from http://www.jeasyui.com. But in my case I want to load at first highest level then when click to one of node load it's child nodes.

```
<ul id="tt" checkbox="true" animate="true"></ul>

  $(function() {
        $('#tt').tree({
                data: @Html.Raw(Model.Tree)
            });
    });
```

on this function I get childs nodes for selected node from DB:

```
$(function() {
        $('#tt').tree({
                onBeforeExpand: function(node) {
                    var hospitalId = node.id;

            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("LoadDepartments")', { hospitalId: hospitalId }, function () {
                });
                }});});

  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LoadDepartments(Guid hospitalId)
        {

            LoadHospitals();
            var departments = _templateAccessor.GetDepartments(hospitalId);
            var hospital = tree.Where(obj => obj.id == hospitalId.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (hospital != null)
            {
                foreach (var department in departments)
                {
                    DataTreeModel dep = new DataTreeModel();
                    dep.id = department.Id.ToString();
                    dep.text = department.Name;
                    dep.state = "closed";
                    hospital.children.Add(dep);
                    hospital.state = "open";
                }
            }

              var result = SerializeToJsonString(tree);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

In method LoadDepartments I have correct structure but the tree doesn't show new elements. the question is how to clean up previous content of tree and fill it with new content, maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Your JavaScript code expects some JSON but your action returns a view. Is that correct?

Comment: I correct  but the result is tghe same

Comment: I would probably replace the last two lines with `return Json(hospital, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 0):

[jqTree](https://github.com/mbraak/jqTree)

This Tree should have the features you require, it's very lightweight and easy to use. I'm not advertising but I was in the same situation a couple of weeks ago, and this offered me a solution. It will also keep track of opened up nodes, etc...